# Where do I pay taxes if I live overseas and get paid in a foreign currency?

Tags: taxes, digital-nomads

I've been traveling the world on a Working Holiday visa, moving every 6 months or 1 year. I'm Italian. I now moved to Canada, first as a tourist, and recently I got a working holiday visa, for a total of 8 months.

I also work remotely for an Australian company that pays me in USD (I have an American bank account).

In which country do I pay my taxes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're not a resident of any country, you generally pay tax as a nonresident in each country where you earned income, only on the income that you earned in that country.

Comment: I suggest a slightly different question: How do you find out what taxes you owe to each country? Each country has its own rules for deciding e.g. whether you are tax resident. Each has its own rules, given your status relative to that country, for determining what taxes you owe on which income. Rules may be affected by relevant tax treaties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Italy has to say:  [Italy deems you resident for tax purposes if you've stayed there at least 183 days in the past tax year](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/italy/index_en.htm).

[You can click here to see if you've become a Canadian resident for tax purposes](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/international-non-residents/information-been-moved/determining-your-residency-status.html).

Canada generally goes by a date of December 31, so if you are resident here December 31, 2017, you would file taxes here for the 2017 tax year (by the deadline of April 30, 2018).

Note that you might need to be careful about health insurance.  For example, in Canada, if you haven't become a resident, you won't qualify for the publicly-funded plans, but if you've ceased to be an Italian resident, you may have no benefits available to you from there.  You'd need to secure insurance from a private insurer.  (Such policies can be acquired by foreigners living in Canada temporarily, but typically aren't valid outside Canada.  Source:  am an insurance broker in Canada.)

Comment: Do you have any source to support your first assertion?  That is certainly not how it works in any place I've ever lived in.  The jurisdictions I'm familiar with define tax residence using criteria that make no mention of foreign tax residence, let alone of the acquisition of foreign tax residence.

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/italy/index_en.htm If he's spent less than 183 days out of the previous 365 in Italy, it looks like he only pays tax on his Italian income in Italy, but that implies that he should pay tax in his main country of residence that year, too.

Comment: someone who spends ninety-some days in each of four countries does not have another main country of residence.  The same could be true of someone who moves every 180 days if the threshold for tax residence is 183 days.

Comment: @phoog I don't think it's that simple.  It'll depend on the country in which you were last resident.  and that makes for some serious homework for the persont to conduct to figure out their tax situation.

Comment: But your own quote ("Italy deems you resident for tax purposes if you've stayed there at least 183 days in the past tax year") implies that a well timed departure from Italy will prevent one from being a tax resident without regard to the acquisition of Canadian residence.

Comment: @phoog I await your better researched answer.

Comment: @qoba the original question focuses on where you pay taxes, and the Italian link I posted in my answer clearly deals with that issue.

Comment: @qoba The Canadian page discusses when you acquire Canadian residency.  Prior to that point, you must be a resident of somewhere.  The asker lives in Italy but is about to become nomadic.  I posted when Italians remain Italians for the purposes of paying tax, and when those who come to Canada become resident in Canada for the purposes of paying tax.  It's the best information I can find, and still better than all the other responses combined :)

Comment: I've revised my answer to lessen the references to residency.  You'll note that the answer still deals with the tax concerns mentioned in the original question. -JM